# How can the windows file system know that files and folders are related?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, ntfs

Yesterday, when saving a web page for analysis, I noticed a peculiar thing:
If I decided to save a "complete web page" (I was Chrome), and then deciding that I want to delete the folder with the related files to just be stuck with the html, *the html file was also deleted, even though it was not in the folder*; just a mere sibling.

This obviously required some meta data for Windows to do: somehow Windows knew that the folder was linked with the file, and decided to delete the file if the folder was also deleted.

I am not sure what the user story was for implementing such a feature was, since it just seems retarded to me, but how does Windows accomplish this?

Comment: I believe it's very simple: if you're trying to delete a folder called {something}_files, Windows Explorer will also check if there's a file called {something}.html around. No magic involved ;)

Comment: Add that as an answer :-) I believe you are right. Just tested it, and it worked after renaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Explorer performs a simple check: if there's a folder called `{something}_files`, it looks for a file `{something}.html` and assumes those two are associated.

It's rather unlikely that someone will create a pair like that by accident, so it's quite safe assumption. Chrome mimics IE's naming when saving webpages, that's why it works.